# How do I convert this to a linear programming problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-programming

It takes a tailoring 2 hours of cutting and 4 hours of sewing to make a knit suit. To make a worsted suit, it takes 4 hours of cutting and 2 hours of sewing. At most 20 hours per day are available for cutting and at most 16 hours per day are available for sewing. The profit on a knit suit is Php340 and on worsted suit is Php310. How many of each kind of suit should be made to maximize profit? What is the maximum profit?

Comment: Can you follow the same pattern as here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1212117/how-do-i-convert-this-into-a-linear-programming-problem

Answer (score 0):

That **is** a "linear programming problem!  I assume you mean you want to write down the target function and constraints.

As always in a problem like this, you start by assigning "labels" to the things you want to determine.  Here, the question is "How many of each suit are made?" so we write "let x be the number or knit suits made and let y be the number of worsted suits made" (You can of course, use what ever letters you want.)

You are told "It takes a tailoring 2 hours of cutting and 4 hours of sewing to make a knit suit." so to make x knit suits, it will take 2x hours of cutting and 4x hours of sewing.  You are told "To make a worsted suit, it takes 4 hours of cutting and 2 hours of sewing" so to make y worsted suits, it will take 4y hours of cutting and 2 hours of sewing.  To make x knit suits and y worsted suits will take 2x+ 4y hours of cutting and 4x+ 2y hours of sewing. You are told "At most 20 hours per day are available for cutting" so $2x+ 4y\le 20$.  You are told "at most 16 hours per day are available for sewing." so $4x+ 2y\le 16$.  Finally, you are told that "The profit on a knit suit is Php340 and on worsted suit is Php310." so with x knit suits and y worsted suits the profit will be 340x+ 310y.

The problem is to maximize 340x+ 310y subject to the constraints $2x+ 4y\le 20$ and $4x+ 2y\le 16$. 
(And, of course, $x\ge 0$, $y\ge 0$.)